# How to add white space to variables?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, amsmath, subscripts, white-space

I use variables in math mode with subscripts  before and after the variable name itself, like

```
{}_{B}\vec{a}_{GP}^{}
```

In case I have equations where these are multiplied, one cannot tell which subscript belongs to which variable anymore.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
R_{GA}^{-1}{}_{G}^{}\vec{a}_{GP}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture showing variables with no whitespace between subscripts]

Therefore I'd like to add a minimal amount of whitespace after each variable. How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: I see no other way than to type `\,` between the two objects.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But what exactly is `,`? Do you also know where `\pos` is defined, i.e. where I can find docs about it?

Comment: `\,` is “add a thin space” and is very useful when two objects in a formula have to be slightly separated; it's the same space that TeX adds automatically between “sin” and “*x*” in `\sin x`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, thats exactly what I needed. I know `\pos` is some substitute for the sub/superscripts, but is this LaTeX, or PGF, or plain TeX. Where can find its documentation? Googling `tex \pos` doesn't result in anything useful.

Comment: Never heard of a general purpose `\pos` macro, sorry. Without a source nothing can be said.

Comment: How or where is `\pos` defined? Moreover, why bother with `\pos` at all, given that `\,` is available and does the job perfectly?

Comment: Nevermind, I just found it. It was defined somewhere in a file I received from someone else. Sorry to have bothered you with this `\pos`and thanks again for your awesome help :-)